# How to setup loggers in Dask using YAML configuration

Tags: python, logging, dask, dask-distributed, python-logging

I am trying to use the dask configuration file to setup the logger in dask as show [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/debugging.html#logs) in the documentation. My `~/.config/dask/dask.yaml` config file is:

```yaml
logging:
  version: 1
  formatters:
      default:
          format: '[%(asctime)s] %(name)s - %(process)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
          datefmt: '%H:%M:%S'
  handlers:
      console:
        class: logging.StreamHandler
        level: INFO
        formatter: default
  loggers:
      distributed:
        level: INFO
        handlers: [console]
```

However, when I run `python -c "from dask.distributed import Client; c = Client()"` the output does not use the specified format:

```
INFO:distributed.http.proxy:To route to workers diagnostics web server please install jupyter-server-proxy: python -m pip install jupyter-server-proxy
INFO:distributed.scheduler:Clear task state
INFO:distributed.scheduler:  Scheduler at:     tcp://127.0.0.1:44923
INFO:distributed.scheduler:  dashboard at:            127.0.0.1:8787
INFO:distributed.nanny:        Start Nanny at: 'tcp://127.0.0.1:46371'
INFO:distributed.nanny:        Start Nanny at: 'tcp://127.0.0.1:44967'
INFO:distributed.nanny:        Start Nanny at: 'tcp://127.0.0.1:34181'
INFO:distributed.nanny:        Start Nanny at: 'tcp://127.0.0.1:33739'
INFO:distributed.worker:      Start worker at:      tcp://127.0.0.1:38271
INFO:distributed.worker:         Listening to:      tcp://127.0.0.1:38271
INFO:distributed.worker:         dashboard at:            127.0.0.1:39511
INFO:distributed.worker:Waiting to connect to:      tcp://127.0.0.1:44923
...
```

If I change the level to DEBUG I also get debug log messages, so it appears that dask is seeing the config file and using it, but the format is not working. I have also tried putting a similar configuration in the `distributed.yaml` file, but I got the same results.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Quite late response:

It looks like something else is setting the log format, because those logs aren't in Dask's default format of `"%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"` (at least until this PR makes it in: https://github.com/dask/distributed/pull/3987/files).

Dask doesn't use the python logger settings, the correct path in the yaml file should be:

```
distributed:
  admin:
    log-format:'[%(asctime)s] %(name)s - %(process)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
```

Dask's documentation lists several locations that it loads the config from: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/configuration.html (Though the environment variable DASK_CONFIG is not obvious in the docs.)

You could try the following to see what Dask thinks it should be outputting the logging as:

```
import dask.config
import dask.distributed
dask.config.refresh()
dask.config.get('distributed.admin.log-format')
```

and in the end if you still can't find why it's set incorrectly, maybe try:

```
dask.config.set({'distributed.admin.log-format':'[%(asctime)s] %(name)s - %(process)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'})
client = dask.distributed.Client()
```